# SwiftUI Lists treat DisclosureGroup content as list items

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm working with Lists in SwiftUI, and the interface seems pretty intuitive. However, if I want more complex views in a list, and I decide to use `DisclosureGroup`, then the List treats the expanded content of the disclosure group as its own list cell. When implementing `onMove` and `onDelete`, this causes undefined behavior.

Consider the following view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($items, id: \.self) { $item in
                DisclosureGroupView()
            }
            .onDelete { indexSet in
                items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            }
            .onMove { indices, newOffset in
                items.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DisclosureGroupView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup {
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                Text("Test text")
                Text("Test text")
                Text("Test text")
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Tap to Expand")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this leads to the following behavior when deleting/reordering:

[image: Demo]

You can see that I can attempt to individually delete/reorder *only* the expanded content of the disclosure group, which in my context does not make sense and leads to undefined behavior; **the entirety of the group should be treated as a single element.**

Assuming that DisclosureGroup is the only option I have for the complex view I wish to implement, how can I make it so that the entire group is treated as a cell, rather than the label and expanded content being treated as different cells?

Answer (score 1):

The final proposal:

When using a custom view, use `DisclosureGroup` and replace `List` with `SrcollView`

Attention: The interface is not perfect yet. If you need to improve it, you can refer to it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8VnH2eEnK4

I didn’t watch the video carefully, but the effect looks good. The source code costs 3 dollars.(o_o)

[image: custom view]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var items: [Item] = (0...5).map { Item(number: $0) }
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Divider()
        ForEach(0 ..< items.count, id: \.self) { i in
          ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            CollapsibleView(item: $items[i])
              .padding()
              .background(Color.white)
              .offset(x: items[i].offset)
              .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged({ gesture in
                  if gesture.translation.width < 0 {
                    // Swipe left to show delete button
                    items[i].offset = gesture.translation.width
                  }
                })
                  .onEnded({ _ in
                    if items[i].offset < -100 {
                      // Swipe far enough, delete the items[i]
                      items[i].offset = -1000
                      withAnimation {
                        delete(item: items[i])
                      }
                    } else {
                      // Not far enough, reset
                      items[i].offset = 0
                    }
                  })
              )
            
            if items[i].offset <= -100 {
              Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                  delete(item: items[i])
                }
              }) {
                Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                  .padding()
                  .background(Color.red)
                  .cornerRadius(8)
              }
              .offset(x: -100) // Adjust the position as needed
            }
          }
          Divider()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  func delete(item: Item) {
    items.removeAll { $0.id == item.id }
  }
}

struct CollapsibleView: View {
  @Binding var item: Item
  
  var body: some View {
    DisclosureGroup(
      isExpanded: $item.isExpanded,
      content: {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
          Text("Detail for item \(item.number)")
          Text("Another detail")
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black) // Set the color here
      },
      label: {
        HStack {
          Text("Item \(item.number)").foregroundColor(.black) // Set the color here
          Spacer()
          Image(systemName: "ellipsis").foregroundColor(.black) // Set the color here
        }
      }
    )
    .animation(.easeInOut, value: item.isExpanded)
    .transition(.opacity)
  }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var number: Int
  var isExpanded: Bool = false
  var offset: CGFloat = 0
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. We do not want each element in the disclosure group to be treated as separate elements (in your screenshot, you can see you cand delete each individual "test text".

Instead, we want the entirety of the disclosure group to be a **single** element, without changing the look of the view/splitting up into two distinct sections as in your screenshot.

Comment: If you want to make it a whole, I think you need to custom a new view instead of using DisclosureGroup. But if you really want to use  the DisclosureGroup, you need to defined a new `struct` for items.

Comment: How does using a struct for items make the default disclosure group work? Also, I have tried using a custom disclosure group that basically replicates the code [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroupstyle) but as a separate component, but it breaks the expansion animation when placed in a list.

Comment: I find someway, please look at the new answer

Comment: Sorry for late, but here it is now.

Comment: I change the answer, but not write a new one.

Comment: You can see in your video that you are able to delete the expanded content of a disclosure group, which is exactly the issue I'm trying to solve. The entire group should be treated as a single element as described in the question.

Comment: I wrote a new custom view, using `SrollView` instead of `List`

Comment: The goal is to use List so we don't have to manually implement onDelete and onMove

Answer (score 0):

You have treat items in DisclosureGroupView like a List then. onDelete method should be there too.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($items, id: \.self) { $item in
                DisclosureGroupView()
            }

        }
    }
}

struct DisclosureGroupView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup {
            // List here
                ForEach... { $item in
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                }
            .onDelete { indexSet in
                ....
            }
            .onMove { indices, newOffset in
                ...
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Tap to Expand")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. We don't want each item within the disclosure group's expanded content to be treated as an element in the list. We want the **entire disclosure group component to be treated as a single cell in the list.**